# Duplicated ID with different Column values in R (dbplyr)

Tags: r, database, dplyr, dbplyr

I'm trying to count people that received a specific coverage from SQL using the dbplyr package in R. The issue here is that I have a `Citizen_ID`  and `Coverage_Number` variables repeated in the same period. One person can have several services registered in the database

```
id <-c(458,215,458,215,265,265,265,349,140,50)
code_born <-  c('6.1','6.2','6.2',"6.2",'6.1','6.1','6.2','6.1','6.2','6.2')
reimburse_code <- c(2518,421,458,421,2518,345,218,479,479,251,NA)
period <- c(20180101,20190212,20180101,20191212,20180526,20170425,20200912,20200505)


data <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,code_born,reimburse_code,period)) 


library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)


data %>% 
  mutate(year = round(as.numeric(period)/10000),
         type_birth = case_when(
                  (duplicated(id) == TRUE & code_born == '6.1' & reimburse_code == 2518) ~ "normal",
                  (duplicated(id) == TRUE & code_born == '6.2' & reimburse_code == 2518) ~ "c-section",
                  (!duplicated(id) == TRUE & code_born == '6.2' & reimburse_code == NA) ~ "c-section",
                  (!duplicated(id) == TRUE & code_born == '6.1' & reimburse_code == NA) ~ "normal",
                  TRUE ~ "Just for illustration"))
```

I get this result:

```
   id    code_born reimburse_code period   year type_birth
   <chr> <chr>     <chr>          <chr>   <dbl> <chr>     
 1 458   6.1       2518           201801…  2018 Just for Illustration
 2 215   6.2       421            201902…  2019 Just for Illustration
 3 458   6.2       458            201801…  2018 Just for Illustration
 4 215   6.2       426            201912…  2019 Just for Illustration
 5 265   6.1       2518           201805…  2018 Just for Illustration
 6 265   6.1       345            201704…  2017 Just for Illustration
 7 265   6.2       218            201809…  2018 Just for Illustration
 8 349   6.1       479            201805…  2018 Just for Illustration
 9 140   6.2       479            202001…  2020 Just for Illustration
10 50    6.2       251            202002…  2020 Just for Illustration
11 458   6.1       NA             201801…  2018 Just for Illustration
```

What should I do for this `Case_when` scenario AND most importantly, I want to extract these values from SQL using dbplyr. I understand that there are variables that are not translated in SQL such a `duplicated(id)` but perhaps there is an easier way to do it.

The final product I'm looking for consist on counting unique ids for each year, grouped by birth type. Issue consists I have codes such as `reimburse_code = 2518` which applies for both `6.1` and `6.2` in `code born` with each being normal birth and cesarean section, respectively. In that case, when there is another row with same id and different `reimburse code` which is uniquely attributed to `6.1 or` 6.2` in same year I could use that row to assign to that person(id) either normal or cesarean section value.

After using `case_when` and grouping by `year` and `n_distinct(id)`, the resultd would be

```
id       birth_type     year
<int>     <chr>         <int>
458      cesarea        2018
215      cesarea        2019
265      cesarea        2018
265      normal         2017
458      normal         2018
349      normal         2018
140      cesarea        2020
```

My desired final output would be:

```
year     bith_type     cases 
<int>      <chr>        <int>
2018       Normal        2
2018       C-section     2
2019       Normal        0
2019       C-section     1
2020       Normal        0
2020       C-section     1
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for the `type_birth` column to your question. Also: 1) look at `?duplicated`; it only marks the repeated values as duplicated, not the first occurrence of a value. Try: `duplicated(c(1,1))`; it evaluates to `c(FALSE, TRUE)`. 2) Writing `duplicated(x) == TRUE` is redundant, you don't need the `== TRUE` part.

Comment: Thank for the observations. Here the updated version

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the key challenges you are facing is how to compute `duplicated` within a database as this function does not have a dbplyr translation defined.

The following provides a way to create a duplicated indicator using translatable dbplyr functions:

```r
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)

data = data.frame(
  id = c(458,215,458,215,265,265,265,349),
  code_born =  c('6.1','6.2','6.2',"6.2",'6.1','6.1','6.2','6.1'),
  reimburse_code = c(2518,421,458,421,2518,345,218,NA),
  period = c(20180101,20190212,20180101,20191212,20180526,20170425,20200912,20200505)
)

# demo with simlutated connection
remote_df = tbl_lazy(data, con = simulate_mssql())

# create duplicated indicator
example_df = remote_df %>%
  mutate(year = round(as.numeric(period)/10000)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  window_order(period) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(is_duplicated = ifelse(rn == 1, FALSE, TRUE))

# check sql translation
example_df %>% show_query()
```

The idea is to number the rows within each id, then every record that is not numbered 1 will be a duplicated. Note you may have to adjust the `group_by` and `window_order` functions to get the indicator to work as preferred.

Following this by `case_when`, `group_by` and `n_distinct(id)` can be done as per your original example. You would use the new column `is_duplicated` instead of `duplicated(id)`.

To get from:

```r
id       birth_type     year
<int>     <chr>         <int>
458      cesarea        2018
215      cesarea        2019
265      cesarea        2018
265      normal         2017
458      normal         2018
349      normal         2018
140      cesarea        2020
```

To your desired final output:

```r
year     bith_type     cases 
<int>      <chr>        <int>
2018       Normal        2
2018       C-section     2
2019       Normal        0
2019       C-section     1
2020       Normal        0
2020       C-section     1
```

I would do the following:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(year, birth_type) %>%
  summarise(cases = n()) %>%
  select(year, birth_type, cases) %>% # sets order of columns
  arrange(year, birth_type) # sets order of rows
```

Note that this will not add the rows with zero counts in. Having these turn up in SQL output, deserves its own question.